# Having trouble with audio timing

Tags: ios, audio

I am having trouble with my audio.

here is the code:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Cheering" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
[audioPlayer play];
```

It will not play like this.  The code steps through just fine but no audio.  If I put a break on the last line and then step through it plays properly.  I have tried everything I can to get this to work but have no clue where to go from here.

It is acting like it needs a delay before the play command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Sure It will Works

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Cheering" withExtension:@"mp3"];
NSAssert(url, @"URL is valid.");
NSError* error = nil;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
if(!audioPlayer)
{
    NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
}     else
{
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay]

before you actually try to play it?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/prepareToPlay

Comment: Tried that and it did the same thing